# Can method calls be preloaded before the line they are on actually executes

Tags: java, io

In my java code, I have two processes. The first process creates a file and the second process uses that file as input to move on.

```
//Process 1
createFileForProcessTwo("foo.txt");

//Process 2
String fp = getFilePath("foo.txt");

System.out.println(fp);
```

After running this program, my program does not return the file path. The java class and foo.txt are all placed in the current working directory so file path is not an issue. As for creating the txt file, that also is not a problem as I have verified that file has been successfully created.

It seems as if `getFilePath()` is executing before `createFileForProcessTwo`. It would also be notable to say that actual instatiation of the String happens after process 1(process two waits for process 1 to finish), but it seems as if specifically the `getFilePath()` call has already been preloaded with nothing.

Essentially my question is: Is it possible for the `getFilePath()` call to return an empty string(because the file does not even exist yet) before Process 1 is completed?

Comment: Do you mean threads or actual processes?

Comment: If you're not spawning threads, methods will run sequentially, and will block further execution until the current running method is done.

Comment: Re-reading the question I am pretty sure you mean threads - but we might need to see the code for 'getFilePath()' and how you are spawning the threads to understand what is happening.

Comment: I'd need to see code for both methods.  As others have pointed out, the term "process" is ambiguous.  Do you mean threads? Methods?

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the code that " waits for process 1 to finish." Can you post more (or all) of your code?